# Login Screen Makes Me Login 4 Times

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

Using Ubuntu 12.04, after coming back from suspend mode, I find that I consistently can't login on first try. It usually makes me have to go through it twice, but then it became 3 times, and now it's 4. I'm gettin' real sick of sitting here typing in my password 4 times before I can get back into my desktop. Is there any known bug that could be causing this?